# Change title setinterval html or JavaScript

Tags: html

My website automatically changes its title when I click on a link. I have used code which changes the title after a certain number seconds, but I've forgotten it. I saw something like `setinterval` or something like that. What is that code?

Comment: Iike setInterval(function() { document.title= Title}, 3000);

Answer (score 0):

You want `setInterval`

```
setInterval(function() {
    //change title
    //document.title = "Some new title";
}, 3000);
```

The `3000` at the end means execute this every 3000 milliseconds (3 seconds).

Comment: @JeffreydeVos -- Always helps to un-comment the code. Mark the answer when you can.

Answer (score 0):

You call it with a function to execute and a period in milliseconds:

```
setInterval(function() {
      // Do something every 2 seconds
}, 2000);
```

[setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)